# How to fix a broken sub connection and wire?

Tags: wire, repair

The wire connecting to my sub has snapped off, and it brought the metal connector piece with it.

I don't want to buy a new sub, but it looks like this is going to be hard to repair. Anyone have advice for me?

The sub:
[image]

The broken part:
[image]

Demonstrating how it is supposed to look:
[image]

The sub wire is broken too:
[image]

Comment: You posted some 8 Mpixel images here. Please don't. They're only shown 630 pixels wide in your browser, and the extra resolution doesn't give you more information. Next time please scale them down before uploading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are *Faston* connectors, or similar. (Faston is a Brand name of TE Connectivity.)

[This one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/42460-2/A27923TR-ND/288348) is to be crimped on the speaker's wire.

[image]

Although you can fix the wire with a pair of pliers too, I would recommend to use the purpose-made crimp tool for it, as the connection will be a lot more reliable. These tools can be pretty expensive, but maybe you can borrow one. Fix the crimped Faston to the speaker's frame with *Tec 7* or something similar.

Note that Faston exists in different tab widths, make sure you buy the right size.

Comment: That speaker's wire must be fixed to something rigid (like the original support) or else vibration from the moving parts can produce rattling and noise. I'm with @kamil on this question: simply re-solder the original contact will work (I've done that more than once)

Comment: @Axeman - Er, yes, I thought that was obvious. I'll add it to my answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Axeman - Forse possiamo continuare in italiano? :-)

Comment: Ahaha potremmo, ma sarebbe off topic e dovresti "moderarci" :-) Comunque mi sono appena accorto di aver scritto una stupidata (non del tutto per colpa mia, oggi stackexchange mi sta dando qualche problema) e quindi cancello il commento :-)

Comment: @axeman - eh, sì, mi domandavo già... :-/. A proposito di moderare ti rendi conto che il nostro nuovo moderatore clabacchio è italiano, vero? Prima potevamo scrivere qualunque cosa in italiano, ma adesso si capicse il moderatore :-)

Comment: Vero, anche se a giudicare dal suo avatar attuale possiamo sempre sperare che sia troppo impegnato con le birre per leggerci. Potresti sempre cercare di corromperlo con litri di Chimay o di Orval. Io mi farei corrompere facilmente... :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4614/discussion-between-axeman-and-stevenvh)

Comment: I ended up using a butt clamp like this to connect the two wires: http://www.buttconnectors.net/images/slide%20in%20first%20wire_1.jpg then, I used a twist tie to keep the new clamped wire away from the sub to avoid rattling. So far so good!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to solder either the metal terminal or the male connector back in place using either a soldering iron or a specialized gas torch. Most people who build or repair electronics should have the tools and skill to fix this problem for a fair price, given that the task would take 10 minutes max.